# What's the rules for using figure captions?

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

For example, I have the following situation:

An/The example of a password is shown in Figure 1.

a picture goes here

*Figure 1 - An/The example of a password*

What article should I use? Should I say "**The** example" or "**An** example"? The question is not about articles, it's more about figure captions and what I should use.

From [this](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/styleforstudents/c4_p12.html) article I see that it may be omitted.

Comment: I assume you can use any password you like, so '*an*' is appropriate here.  (If you could only one, '*the*' should be used)

Comment: No, I meant "should I say The example or An example" :) Sorry for that

Comment: If there's only one example of what a password is, you'd say "the" to tell the reader that this example is the definitive example. Since there are obviously more than one examples of passwords, you'd say "an".

As you found elsewhere, your third option is to omit the article completely and just say "Example of a password". This is valid, and best-suited for formal reading.